# SearchCursor RuntimeError: Underlying DBMS error [ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected]

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, cursor, oracle-dbms, runtimeerror

I need load OBJECTID from remote DB but I'm still getting error:

> **RuntimeError: Underlying DBMS error [ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected] [SDEDO.E_EL_TU][STATE_ID = 22362]**

I don't know why. After all, sql statement compiles SearchCursor do why I'm getting this error?

My code looks this:

```
import arcpy

obj_id = 0
table = "C:\\Temp\\My_connection.sde\\SDEDO.E_EL_TU"

    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_table=table, field_names=["OBJECTID"], sql_clause=("TOP 1", "ORDER BY OBJECTID DESC")) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            obj_id = row[0]
            break
```

I was googling for a long time but nowhere is topic with this error and SearchCursor.

Answer (score 2):

`TOP` is not recognized by Oracle, so fetch all records and read only the first 10 ones.

From the [`arcpy.da.SearchCursor` documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) for the `sql_clause` parameter:

> Note:
>
> ...
>
> TOP is only supported by SQL Server databases.